# php coding error not returning to main page

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Im new to Php so please be gentle.

I have written a website and i have added a subscribe to newsletter section. The user adds their name and email address before pressing submit. I get the email so the most part is working but the form doesnt return me to the main page of the website. Can anyone point out where i am going wrong please?

Thanks in advance

The code on the website is:

```
<form name="frmcontact" id="frmcontact" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Name"
      onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'Name' : this.value;"              onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Name') ? '' : this.value;" />
 <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Email" 
 onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'Email' : this.value;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Email') ? '' : this.value;" />
<input name="submit" id="send" type="submit" value="Message" />
</form>


The code in contact.php is:

<?php session_start();

if(!$_POST) exit;

    $address = 'email@emailaddress.com';
    $email_subject ="Add me to the mailing list";
    $email    = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name     = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject  = "Please add me to the mailing list ";

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comment = stripslashes($comment); }


         $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

         $msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject.\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "$message\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "You can contact $name via email, $email.\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

        if(@mail($address, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
        {echo "<p class='ajax_success'>Thanks for Contact Us.</p>"; }
         else
         {echo "<p class='ajax_failure'>Sorry, Try again Later.</p>"; }
    header('Location:http://www.websiteaddress/homepage.html');
?>
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: command the echo lines and try

Comment: did you tried my step ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove All output before `header` use `exit` after `header` and also consider to give space marked below

```
                 v
header('Location: http://www.websiteaddress/homepage.html');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

use correct directory path

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $address = 'email@emailaddress.com';
    $email_subject ="Add me to the mailing list";
    $email    = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name     = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject  = "Please add me to the mailing list ";

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comment = stripslashes($comment); }


         $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

         $msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject.\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "$message\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "You can contact $name via email, $email.\r\n\n";
         $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

        if(@mail($address, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
        {echo "<p class='ajax_success'>Thanks for Contact Us.</p>"; }
         else
         {echo "<p class='ajax_failure'>Sorry, Try again Later.</p>"; }
            header('Location: homepage.html');
}
```

Comment: Where should i change the directory path?

Answer (score 0):

you cant output anything before using the header()

HTTP-Headers should be sent before any output from the server. If you have an output before, the server will output a warning like 'Headers already been sent'

```
<?php
 ob_start();

  echo "redirecting now ....";
  header('Location: http://www.websiteaddress/homepage.html');
  exit();

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```